# Error Occurred When Reviewing this Item

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

I am currently trying to review Low Quality Posts, but every time I flag a question, the flag gets submitted but it comes back with:

> Error Occurred When Reviewing this Item

[image: Screenshot]

I then have to skip to get to next item, though my flag has been created.

This is occurring a lot, but the rest of SO is working correctly for me, and this used to work.

- Is anybody else experiencing this issue?
- Has something changed?

I am running:

- Chrome 30.0.1599.101
- OS X Mavericks

---

Update:

I have tested in Firefox on the same machine and can't reproduce. So either the error was intermittent or isolated to Chrome. I'm having to wait for more Low Quality posts to appear so I can test again in Chrome.

---

Update (2):

I have tested again in Chrome and the issue **is** still occurring.

---

**Resolved:**

Issue was caused by the local browser cache. It must have cached a broken script.

Comment: no repro in Win 7 / IE 11

Comment: I'll try another browser to see if I can reproduce, but Low Quality Answers aren't that frequent in the review queue for me.

Comment: that is true, I'm waiting for VLQ items to repro in Chrome...

Comment: Hmmm, that is unfortunate but I don't have a repro on Chrome 31.0 on Win7. Is it only happening for you in that review queue?

Comment: @rene Yeah only in that review queue, which is why I thought it was odd, and only if I raised a flag first. But I couldn't reproduce in firefox, so I suspect I was just unlucky and there has been an intermittent error. I suppose if the error message was more verbose, I wouldn't have to chase trying to figure out if the problem is my end or StackOverflow end.

Comment: Well, if I notice the same error I'll leave comment here. Nasty bugs...

Comment: @rene I just tried the queue again in Chrome and reproduced it. So it's not that intermittent for me it seems.

Comment: @Scott: Do you have any userscripts installed? Try clearing your cache (CTRL + F5) to see if there's something dodgy in there (in Chrome, obviously).

Comment: @Matt No user scripts, I'll give the cache clear a try. I'll also try and Chrome Developer console to see if I can spot a bad request.

Comment: I have reviewed several low quality posts on Arqade today in Chrome and haven't experienced this issue

Comment: @Flyk I suspect if others aren't complaining it's just me. Just thought it was worth reporting in case others were seeing it. I am waiting for new flaggable low quality posts, now that I have cleared my cache, and have the console open to watch what happens.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Technically they duplicate mine. But seeing they gained more popularity, and hence more headway into the issue this one can be closed.

Comment: I did agonize over which way around to do the duplication as earlier should normally get precedence, but the other had an official status tag...so I did things backwards.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah it's cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this went out a few builds ago.  There are race conditions that happen in the review queues quite often that aren't malicious attempts to bypass valid options...these are now hopefully all accounted for.  I'll be watching the logs for any more cases that popup and whitelist them as well if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Matt for the suggestion to clear the cache - though why I never thought to do that myself, makes me a little bit embarrassed that that fixed it. :)

Must have been a broken script cache by Chrome. Crisis averted, all systems go.

---

Seems I am not the only one experiencing this issue:
["An error occurred when reviewing this item"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211429/an-error-occured-when-reviewing-this-item)

Maybe I got lucky after my cache clearing.

Comment: Caching. It's always caching...